# Error while doing migration (index name already exist)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I am trying to migrate my latest update of my website using ruby on rails.

but it seems to error when I was doing migration. it appears

```
    Index name 'index_jasa_images_on_jasa_id' on table 'jasa_images' already exists/home/lukni/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:936:in `add_index_options'
```

this is my migration file 20190613073018_create_jasa_images.rb

```
    class CreateJasaImages < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :jasa_images do |t|
          t.references :jasa, index: true, foreign_key: true
          t.string :image
          t.timestamps null: false
        end
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm, you can try to `add_index` via command.

```
create_table :jasa_images do |t|
  t.references :jasa
  t.string :image
  t.timestamps null: false
end

add_index : jasa_images, :jasa_id, name: 'your_custom_index_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing, from rails console first remove the indexes of that field

`ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_index "jasa_images", name: "index_jasa_images_on_jasa_id"`

then, you can add a new index in the migration file

```
create_table :jasa_images do |t|
 ...
end

add_index : jasa_images, :jasa_id, name: 'index_name'
```

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Khanh's answer, you can add the index after; and add on `unless index_exists?`

```
create_table :jasa_images do |t|
  t.references :jasa
  t.string :image
  t.timestamps null: false
end

add_index : jasa_images, :jasa_id, name: 'your_custom_index_name' unless index_exists?(:jasa_images, :jasa_id)
```